# turbo-sprockets-rails3 not supporting deploy rollbacks properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, asset-pipeline, sprockets

Turbo sprockets seems to fail for the following case:

1. Make some changes in existing css file in a branch.
2. Run assets:precompile rake task.
3. The css file will be compiled by this gem.
4. Now checkout/rollback to old commit after which css file was modified.
5. Running precompile rake task will not compile the css file and it still contains the changes done to the css file in the later commit.

**Expected Result**: The css file should be compiled again as it has been restored to previous state.

**EDIT:**
Relevant code from application.rb

```
#for PDF
config.middleware.use PDFKit::Middleware, :print_media_type => true

# Enable the asset pipeline
config.assets.enabled = true

# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
config.assets.version = '1.0'
config.middleware.use I18n::JS::Middleware

config.sass.preferred_syntax = :sass
config.generators.stylesheet_engine = :sass
config.generators.template_engine = :slim

config.cache_store = :file_store, "tmp/cache" # specifying the cache store to file_store with the default tmp/cache dir

## Append path to the end of routes file to catch routing errors specifically.
config.after_initialize do |app|
  app.routes.append{ match '*a', :to => 'application#error_404' } unless config.consider_all_requests_local
end
```

from environments/production.rb :

```
config.cache_classes = true

# Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

# Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
config.serve_static_assets = false

# Compress JavaScripts and CSS
config.assets.compress = true

# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
config.assets.compile = true

# Generate digests for assets URLs
config.assets.digest = true
```

Comment: Did you `rake assets:clean`?

Comment: @ptd, rake assets:clean removes compiled assets, then what will be the use of turbo-sprockets-rails3 gem.

Comment: Can you post your config/application.rb and config/emvironments/production.rb?

Comment: @eabraham Question updated with above details..

Comment: what command are you executing for your "checkout/rollback"?

Comment: @phoet git checkout <branch_id>

Comment: @PranabGupta you need to deploy the right SHA to production, are you sure that you are not actually deploying master?

Answer (score 0):

Change the following files:

environments/production.rb:

```
# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
config.assets.compile = false
```

application.rb

```
# Enable the asset pipeline
config.assets.enabled = false
```

Comment: using this configuration assets are not getting precompiled using "rake assets:precompile"